# Listing current pages subp page in list items in the sidebar

Tags: php, theme-development, sidebar, wp-list-pages

I'm wanting to list my current page's child pages as list items in the sidebar of my wordpress site.

So far I've been referencing the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

I'm unsure how to set it to show just my subpages, so far I have this:

```
<?php $args = array(
'depth'        => 0,
'show_date'    => '',
'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
'child_of'     => 0,
'exclude'      => '',
'include'      => '',
'title_li'     => __('Title'),
'echo'         => 1,
'authors'      => '',
'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
'link_before'  => '',
'link_after'   => '',
'walker'       => '',
'post_type'    => 'page',
    'post_status'  => 'publish' 
 ); 

 wp_list_pages($args);

?>
```

It returns:

```
Title
  Home
   Child 1
   Child 2
  Sample Page
```

I'm just wanting the child pages (in this case 1 & 2). I don't want to show Home and Sample Page either.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way you add in "exclude" parameter like this

'exclude'      => '', // here add this page id you don't show in listing.

'exclude'      => '2,4', like this

If you want only child pages you will use get_page_children() function.

Please see this link for reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children